# When i run below code to click on 3rd button iam getting error can anyone help me

Tags: selenium

When i run below code to click on  3rd button iam getting error can anyone help me

```
String cssSelectorOfSameElements="input[type='button'][id='view_button_color1']";
List<WebElement> a=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorOfSameElements));

//driver.findElement(By.id("view_button_color1")).click();
a.get(3).click();
```

Comment: print this value a.size() before clicking.

Comment: provide more details about exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask read this to understand how to answer question. What error you are getting. what is the html code. without this how someone can answer the question.

Comment: <div class="col-md-4" align="right">
<div id="mobile_view_button00" class="">
<b class="content_date_allignment hide-nav">Posted Date : 14-04-2017</b>
<a class="hide-content" target="_blank" href="https://www.perfectprofile.net/software-engineer-senior-software-engineer-python-jobs-in-jouve-india-pvt-ltd-2638">
<button id="view_button_color1" class="btn btn-primary view_button_color1" type="button">view</button>
</a>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score -1):

Add wait before clicking on element

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("view_button_color1")));
```

Make sure that locator is correct and check once as above

Let me know if you face issue